# Calling updateDateRangeInput within a Shiny module

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have a Shiny application with multiple `plot_ly` charts on a single page using the same date range. For complicated reasons, I would like each chart in a separate module and be reactive to `plot_ly` zooms.

The way I did this pre-module was to capture `plotly_relayout` and have it call `updateDateRangeInput` to set the entire page to that range, which then cascaded through my other `plot_ly` charts. Now that we're modularizing these charts, I'm unable to have the same behavior. I capture the redraw event, but calling `updateDateRangeInput` on the parent date range seems to have no effect.

I've tried using the namespace's session as well as passing the parent's session and calling with it.

### Very simplified code:

app.R:

```
library(shiny)

source("mod.R", local = TRUE)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  chartTimeseriesUI("myseries")
  , dateRangeInput("dateRange", "Select Date Range:"
                   , start = Sys.Date() - 600
                   , end = Sys.Date()
                   , min = Sys.Date() - 1200
                   , max = Sys.Date()
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(chartTimeseries, id = "myseries", reactive(input$dateRange), session)
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

mod.R:

```
chartTimeseriesUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotlyOutput(outputId = ns("timeseries"))
}

chartTimeseries <- function(input, output, session, dateRange, psession) {
  regionRedraw <- reactive({
    print("I'm in redraw")
    d <- event_data("plotly_relayout", source = "timeseries") 
    if(is.null(d)) { # double click
      startdate <- Sys.Date() - 600
      enddate <- Sys.Date() 
    } else {
      xstart <- d$`xaxis.range[0]`
      xend <- d$`xaxis.range[1]`

      if (is.null(xstart)) { 
        startdate <- Sys.Date() - 600
        enddate <- Sys.Date()
      } else {
        # Take our X time and convert it out of milliseconds
        startdate <- as.POSIXlt(xstart/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="America/New_York")  
        enddate <- as.POSIXlt(xend/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="America/New_York")
      }
    }

    absmindate <- Sys.Date() - 1200
    absmaxdate <- Sys.Date() 
    updateDateRangeInput(psession, dateRange, label="Now for a new range:", start=startdate, end=enddate, min=absmindate, max=absmaxdate)
  })

  observe({
    print("date range changed!")
    d <- regionRedraw()
  })

  output$timeseries <- renderPlotly({
    rangestart <- dateRange()[1]
    rangeend <- dateRange()[2]
    diff_in_days = as.numeric(difftime(rangeend, rangestart, units = "days"))
    tm <- seq(0, diff_in_days, by = 10)
    x <- rangeend - tm
    y <- rnorm(length(x))

    p <- plot_ly(x = ~x
                , y = ~y
                , type = "scatter"
                , mode = "markers"
                , text = paste(tm, "days from today")
                , source = "timeseries")
  })
}
```

### Output

```
[1] "date range changed!"
[1] "I'm in redraw"
```

And then when I select a region, I get:

```
[1] "date range changed!"
[1] "I'm in redraw"
```

And the plot zooms in, the date range does not change to the new selection and the `dateRangeInput` label does not change.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Your `dateRangeInput` is outside of your module, so you can't directly interact with it from inside your module. I believe the correct way to do what you want is to update the input from outside the module using return or to put the Date input in the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by updating the date range outside of the module:
The module:

```
chartTimeseriesUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotlyOutput(outputId = ns("timeseries"))
}

chartTimeseries <- function(input, output, session, dateRange) {
  regionRedraw <- reactive({
    print("I'm in redraw")
    d <- event_data("plotly_relayout", source = "timeseries") 
    if(is.null(d)) { # double click
      startdate <- Sys.Date() - 600
      enddate <- Sys.Date() 
    } else {
      xstart <- d$`xaxis.range[0]`
      xend <- d$`xaxis.range[1]`

      if (is.null(xstart)) { 
        startdate <- Sys.Date() - 600
        enddate <- Sys.Date()
      } else {
        # Take our X time and convert it out of milliseconds
        startdate <- as.POSIXlt(xstart/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="America/New_York")  
        enddate <- as.POSIXlt(xend/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="America/New_York")
      }
    }

    absmindate <- Sys.Date() - 1200
    absmaxdate <- Sys.Date()
    # reactive list instead of update
    list(dateRange=dateRange(),start=startdate, end=enddate-1, min=absmindate, max=absmaxdate)    
  })

  observe({
    print("date range changed!")
    d <- regionRedraw()
  })

  output$timeseries <- renderPlotly({
    rangestart <- dateRange()[1]
    rangeend <- dateRange()[2]
    diff_in_days = as.numeric(difftime(rangeend, rangestart, units = "days"))
    tm <- seq(0, diff_in_days, by = 10)
    x <- rangeend - tm
    y <- rnorm(length(x))

    p <- plot_ly(x = ~x
                 , y = ~y
                 , type = "scatter"
                 , mode = "markers"
                 , text = paste(tm, "days from today")
                 , source = "timeseries")
  })
  # return list to update date input later
  return(reactive(regionRedraw()))
}
```

Example App:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
source("mod.R", local = TRUE)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  chartTimeseriesUI("myseries")
  , dateRangeInput("dateRange", "Select Date Range:"
                   , start = Sys.Date() - 600
                   , end = Sys.Date()-1
                   , min = Sys.Date() - 1200
                   , max = Sys.Date()
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # receive return
  z <- callModule(chartTimeseries, id = "myseries", 
                  reactive(input$dateRange))

  observe({
    vals <- z()
    # update date
    updateDateRangeInput(session, "dateRange",start=vals$start,end=vals$end)
  })


})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Cleverly done! I had tried returning something, but couldn't figure out the placement or encapsulation. This was just the thing. Thanks!